# Add tick at zero with label 0

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to get a label "0" at the origin to display. Currently it is not displaying (code below). Other tick labels work fine, just not at zero. I suppose I could use `Epilog` to add text at (0,0), but then I would have to style the text similarly to the tick labels. Any ideas how to get the tick at (0,0) to show itself?

```
plot1 = Plot[2*x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {{{0,"0"}, 1}, {0, 1}}]
plot2 = RegionPlot[{x >= y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True, Ticks -> {{{0, 0}, {0.5, "a"}, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Plot[2*x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> {{{0, "0"}, 1}, {0, 1}},  
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot[{x >= y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True, Ticks -> {{{0, 0}, {0.5, "a"}, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]